# PHP Echo a value to Paypal (Encrypted)

Tags: php, html, forms, encryption, paypal

I'm creating a custom checkout page that then heads to the paypal site for payment, i have successfully sent the correct info to paypal using this:

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="I@AmNotPostingMyRealEmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<?php $cart = $_SESSION['cart']; ?>
<?php $total = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
$navcartsql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$key";
$navcartres = mysqli_query($connection, $navcartsql);
$navcartr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($navcartres); ?>
<?php if ($value['Extras']==""){
   $Extra =  0;} else{$Extra = 2;} 
  if ($value['ExtrasB']==""){
     $Extri =  0;} else{$Extri = 2;} 
  if ($value['Sauce']=="" or $value['Sauce']=="No-Sauce"){
   $Extra1 = 0;} else{$Extra1 = 0.5;} 
  if ($value['Addons']==""){
   $Addi = 0;} else{$Addi = 1;} 
  if ($value['AddonsB']==""){
  $Addo = 0;} else{$Addo = 1;} 
   $subtotal = ($Extri+$Addi+$Addo+$Extra1+$Extra+$navcartr['price']); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $navcartr['name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $subtotal;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $value['quantity']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="on0_<?php echo $count;?>" value="Sauce">
<input type="hidden" name="os0_<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $value['Sauce']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="on1_<?php echo $count;?>" value="Extras">
<input type="hidden" name="os1_<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $value['Extras']; echo ", "; ?><?php echo $value['ExtrasB']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="on2_<?php echo $count;?>" value="Addon's">
<input type="hidden" name="os2_<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $value['Addons']; echo ", "; echo $value['AddonsB']; ?>">
<?php } ?>

<button type="submit" class="button btn-lg">Pay Now: Paypal/Card</button>
</form>
```

and it is working great... the only problem is, I got no idea how to have it encrypted so people cant just Ctrl-Shift-I it and change it to $0.
I know how to create an encrypted PayPal button but only with a set price, name etc... So if anyone can point me in the right direction on the best way to do this is or can help me out that would be great. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You could create 2 different pages. One with the form containing an "item_id", then another php script that receives that item_id and sends to PayPal the cURL request with the corresponding informations of that item_id. Then you can redirect the user to the PayPal page that you have got from the cURL response. This way users cannot edit the informations you submit to PayPal as you are doing it server side and the only information they see is the item_id.